# Why wont my compressed cobblestone craft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

The [Extra Utilities](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1776056-164forge-extra-utilities-v102/) mod allows players to craft compressed cobblestone using normal cobblestone. Only for some reason in my new server it no longer seems to work. If you put the recepie in the crafting table, you can see the finished product in its box, but when you attempt to pick it up from the crafting table, it seems to pick up, then almost instantly goes back to its 'finished' slot.  Why wont it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the mod being installed client side, somehow the server never received the Extra Utilities mod, which caused the issue.